# javascript HTTP GET using Fetch API returns 401 Unauthorized but works in Postman

Tags: javascript

*I've searched for already solved similar answers but no one helped, maybe I missed some small but important detail, please give me a hint.*

I'm trying to make ordinary **HTTP GET authorized request using Fetch API**. It successfully works in Postman, but I cannot reproduce the same success in form of js code...((

The js code: https://codepen.io/iexcept/pen/jpEQgm?editors=1011

```
var url = 'https://core1.dev.bravais.com/api/v3/context/update';
document.cookie = 'Bravais-dev-Context="pP9xIpeU3JXF6+KIVtz2P/8bXJUq5A5FtRSfhDpA2ZrAgUqDOZZfuKnMvLPncMuDgj2Su8trzdDAzB5kAOcAmVD5sh95KdIBRlkyioIZeds8rXn0kk6XjfkWHs/L4jNZYWho4RsW3nELC4u9pO/V4uX6LhsG/LI7Qwsgtd0NTNj4aN4/uu92bESX2F0UZv5SZmRPsdtnCB1pIXpqf0KZ5ZqRdd8+R/wuHfeb6jsy5QI=";Domain=.dev.bravais.com;Path=/;Secure';
fetch(url, {
  credentials: 'include', // include the cookie needed for authorization
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log(data) // Prints result from `response.json()`
})
.catch(error => console.error(error.toString()));
```

> "TypeError: Failed to fetch"

Even the Chrome's ~"Allow CORS" extension doesn't help. It's installed and enabled:

[image]

But! the request works fine in the Postman app (with added the same auth cookie of course), proof:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try the same code outside of a browser? ( nodeJS)

Comment: I hope that's not a valid auth cookie you just gave everyone in the world...

Comment: This seems like a CORS issue to me.